# how to clean one projectfile with devenv?

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction, compilation, devenv

How can I clean a single vc project file? I tried this:

```
devenv SolutionName.sln /Clean SolnConfigName The\Path\to\the\FileToClean.vcproj
```

but it dosn't work. How can I do it? thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to the MSDN reference for [/Clean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ak1w89s%28VS.80%29.aspx) the syntax is:

> devenv /clean SolnConfigName
>   SolutionName [/project ProjName]
>   [/projectconfig ProjConfigName]

For example:

> devenv /clean Debug "C:\Documents and
>   Settings\someuser\My Documents\Visual
>   Studio\Projects\MySolution\MySolution.sln"
>   /project
>   "CSharpWinApp\CSharpWinApp.csproj"
>   /projectconfig Debug

Answer (score 0):

I replaced "The\Path\to\the\FileToClean.vcproj" with "FileToClean". Now it works